# Why is my function not getting called properly?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that will greet somebody (given name) and then ask them how many hours they worked and how much their hourly pay is. The program runs but is not spitting back the correct math. I'm getting this for my answer... `you earned<function wage at 0x00EA9540>`

I have already tried calling payment but not getting an answer with that either.

```
def greet(greeting):
    name = input("Hi, whats your name?")
    return greeting + name

print(greet ("Hey "))



hourly = input("How much is your hourly wage?")
hours = input("How many hours did you work this week?")


def wage(hourly, hours):
    if hours > 40:
        payment = 40 * hourly
        payment = payment + hourly * (hours-40) * 1.5
        return payment
    else:
            return hours * hourly
print("you earned" + str(wage))
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the parameters to the `wage` function.

in your case, it just prints the memory address of the function `wage`...

you need to change the print call with the correct parameters to the `wage` function:

```
print("you earned" + str(wage(hourly, hours)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `wage` function with the parameters:

```
 print("you earned" + str(wage(hourly, hours)))
```

Otherwise you are simply printing the string representation of the `wage` function object, and that doesn't really make much sense.